# Django URLs file redirecting the different URLs to the wrong html files

Tags: python, django

My Django site isn't working properly. It's hard to explain but when I run my Django web server and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ I see "Hello, World!" as expected. But when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/ I see the same thing, when I should be seeing "Hello". There is to much code to put on stack overflow and it won't make sense so I made a GitHub repo https://github.com/Unidentified539/stackoverflow.

Comment: Share the `urls.py`.

Comment: look at the path of dashboard

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do I do that?

Comment: @AlexD'ago please be more clear.

Comment: use include with your urls.py app file,and set all the paths in your urls.py app file

Comment: You have two same path for home page

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.pomo,name="pomo"),
    path("agenda/",views.agenda,name="agenda"),
    path("notes/",views.notes,name="notes"),
  
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to simplify your life

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.pomo,name="pomo"),
    path("agenda/",views.agenda,name="agenda"),
    path("notes/",views.notes,name="notes"),
  
]
```

this is your urls.py file in you app

just type this in your project urls.py so you don’t make a mess with paths and includes

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include('pomofocus.urls'))
]
```

this is just an example you need to enter your own paths and views

Comment: vote up my answer so I can start my climb to become a stack legend ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like in
***practice/urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from practice import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
    path("dashboard", views.dashboard, name='dashboard')

]
```

***Project1 urls.py***

```
import practice.urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(" ", include('practice.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Which urls.py should look like that? I have two one in the app folder and one in the root.

Comment: @Mr. Morningstar I have corrected my ans please check . Sorry I dii not notice this earlier

Comment: No problem I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

**What's your code problem?**

According to your code, you have two same paths for the home page, and when you enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/` Django look at the project-level urls.py (in your code djangoProject1/urls.py) and knows that must go in app-level urls.py (in your code practice/urls.py) and in this file, you have two same paths, and Django uses the first one so you get write page because first one is related to hello view and when you type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/` Django again look at the project-level urls.py and knows that must go in app-level urls.py and in this file again use the first path and you get incorrect HTML file (because both paths are the same and Django always use the first one)

**How to fix this?**

in project-level url.py set both paths to '' and in app-level set your project-level paths. (in other words, replace paths in app-level and project-level

djangoProject1/urls.py:

```
import practice.urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('practice.urls')),
]
```

practice/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from practice import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard')

]
```